QGIS 3.22.16 Atlas margin around feature is greyed out
I am using QGIS 3.22.16. I am using the Atlas to produce multiple maps. However I want to change the scale for each map. I can see the option "Margin around Feature" is greyed out.
Is there a solution to enable this option?
Problem solved see below. "Margin around features" only works for Lines and Polygons. I buffered my point to 1 meter and use those polygons.

Plase provide more details on your atlas, especially a screenshot of your settings.

I found out what was wrong. The "Margin around feature" only works for Lines, Polygons not points. So I buffered my points (1 meter) and export as polygons. Then I used those polygons in the Atlas.  Now I have the 3 scale options available.
